# Python update inherited class level dictionary

Tags: class, inheritance, dictionary, python-3.x

I'm looking for a clean, simple way to update class-level dictionaries, which are inherited from base classes. For example:

```
class Foo(object):
    adict = {'a' : 1}

class Bar(Foo):
    adict.update({'b' : 2})  # this errors out since it can't find adict
```

so that:

```
Foo.adict == {'a' : 1}
Bar.adict == {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}
```

I'd prefer to not use instances here, and if possible not use class methods either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that even if that worked, you'd update the same dictionary instead of creating a new one (so `Foo.adict is Bar.adict` and thus `Foo.adict == Bar.adict`).

In any case, the simplest way is to explicitly refer to the parent class's dict (and copy it, see above):

```
class Bar(Foo):
    adict = dict(Foo.adict)
    adict.update({'b': 2})
```

Comment: Thanks - this definitely works - was hoping that I could figure out something a bit more generic (e.g. like super) that didn't involve referencing the parent class explicitly besides the inheritance.

Comment: You aren't really using much inheritance here, since you use class dictionaries. You can just just a global dict instead. Same effect.

Answer (score 2):

I met this problem too. I solved it by using a metaclass, which may also work with multiple inheritance:

```
import six


class CheckerMeta(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        new_class = super(CheckerMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

        base_configs = [bc.config for bc in bases if hasattr(bc, 'config')]
        configs = base_configs + [new_class.config]

        new_class.config = {}
        for config in configs:
            new_class.config.update(config)

        return new_class


class BaseChecker(six.with_metaclass(CheckerMeta)):
    config = {}


class CheckerA(BaseChecker):
    config = {'a': 1}


class CheckerB(BaseChecker):
    config = {'b': 2}


class CheckerC(CheckerA, CheckerB):
    config = {'c': 3}


assert CheckerA.config == {'a': 1}
assert CheckerB.config == {'b': 2}
assert CheckerC.config == {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3}
```

Answer (score 0):

"I'd prefer to not use instances here, and if possible not use class methods either."

Right. So don't.

```
foo_adict =  {'a' : 1}

def B():
   foo_adict.update({'b': 2})
```

I'm not sure why you use class attribute level dictionaries, it rarely behaves in a useful or expected way.

Comment: Class members *have* their uses. True, they're advanced, but they're not nearly as bad as globals, and not equivalent - you can have (as in my code snippet) seperate values per class. The code base I'm working on right now uses class members in a few places, though admittedly it's for heavy metaprogramming. Besides making logical grouping more obvious, `classmethod`s gotta get the data they work on from *somewhere*.

Comment: class members have their uses. Class member *dictionaries* (or other mutables) typically do not.

Comment: to give a bit of context, I'm using this method of organization to build an API. For example, I'd like for Foo.adict['a'] and Bar.adict['a'] to have the ability to be initialized with a different value, though for most variables they will be the same. The dictionaries won't be modified after the class definition. I also need Foo and Bar to have static attributes, which are not inherited. I don't see why using class member dictionaries is inherently a bad idea

Comment: @mlauria: "The dictionaries won't be modified after the class definition" - And in that case, I will again recommend that you don't have them as class instances. Especially since it is an API. This is a confusing API for the users of the API and they will start modifying the dictionary, and it will not behave like they expect. Options are global dictionaries, not having dictionaries at all but just class members directly, and some sort of read-only dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `adict` in `Foo` class and in `Bar` initialize by calling `init` of `super` then `update`.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.adict = {'a': 1}


class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
        self.adict.update({'b': 2})
```

Example:

```
In [14]: b = Bar()
In [15]: b.adict
Out[15]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```